# Highcharts accessibility enter and click events function

Tags: highcharts, accessibility

I need to add Enter or Spacebar event for accessibility. it works when you click from mouse but doesn't work with Enter or Spacebar

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
                allowPointSelect: false,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            events: {
                      click: function(e) {
                      alert(this.series.name + " clicked")
                          const point = e.point;
                          this.goToBackgroundData(point.answerId);
                      }
                  },
```

Comment: Hi @fguru, You probably are looking for `point.events`: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.point.events Event: mouseOver is fired when a screen reader is focusing on a series/point and click is fired after enter key is pressed. Here you can easily check which events are fired: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/83mcrpxn/