# Highcharts accessibility enter and click events function (need event data accessible）

Tags: highcharts, accessibility

As a follow up to [Highcharts accessibility enter and click events function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68930980/highcharts-accessibility-enter-and-click-events-function)

```js
 plotOptions: {
    series: {
      point: {
        events: {
          click: function(e) {
            console.log('point clicked!')
            console.log('point e: ', e);
          },
          mouseOver: function() {
            console.log('point mouse over!');
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I actually need this event click accessible by keyboard navigation as well.
We already defined the event mouseOver.

I've tried the comments from this: [Highcharts accessibility enter and click events function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68930980/highcharts-accessibility-enter-and-click-events-function)

**I actually need this event click accessible by keyboard navigation**

**more specifically, I need to be able to get the event value as well**

Answer (score 0):

I tested the click event and works fine. MouseOver is fired when a screen reader is focusing on a series/point and click is fired after enter key is pressed.

**Example config for tests:**

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      point: {
        events: {
          click: function() {
            console.log('point clicked!')
          },
          mouseOver: function() {
            console.log('point mouse over!');
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [1,2,3,4]
  }]
});
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2a3v7fk6/show

Comment: Hi - thank you for the comment! though I need to have the event as the parameter. Demo; [https://jsfiddle.net/xam5pn9s/1/show](https://jsfiddle.net/xam5pn9s/1/show), you can see the event e has different values when using keyboard and mouse, and the library does not allow me to go into the target's value when I'm using keyboard - that's where I got the issue

Comment: That is correct, the values for the `event.target` property are different, however, when I test it based on the demo you provided, I am able to get the target value through keyboard input (pressing Enter) on my end. Are you able to provide more details for this use case?

Comment: yeah that's the interesting part. in jsfiddle it works, but in IDE, this piece of code is not allow: `console.log('point e: ', e.target.points.options);` the error message indicates that options is not existing.

Comment: You cannot get access to points this way, from the point event. Did you mean `e.target.point.options`?

Comment: oh yes you;re right